# Emacs Prelude, Smartparens, and OsX

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks, emacs-prelude

I'm using OSX 10.9, iTerm2, Emacs Prelude, and Clojure with all the modes that entails most relevantly, `smartparens`. Good so far.

The short version is: has anybody out there found a harmonious way to use all of this together with OSX Mission Control?

The longer version goes: I want to be able to use commands like `sp-forward-slurp-sexp`, which has a default keybinding of `C-<right>`, better known as the default OS-level shortcut for "switch Spaces right via Mission Control." I can re-map that fairly easily (say, to `C-Shift-<right>`) -- but now, I discover that `C-<right>` actually seems to be sending something like `M-[1;4A`. Instead of triggering `sp-forward-slurp-sexp`, you get `sp-wrap-with-pair "["`. Uhm.

I dug up this [dissertation on re-mapping keys](http://offbytwo.com/2012/01/15/emacs-plus-paredit-under-terminal.html), which is very thorough, but also involves re-mapping rather a deal of stuff, then disabling the parts of `paredit` that are listening for the `M-[` command. While this technically seems to work, I actually rather like having `sp-wrap-with-pair` enabled. Perhaps a better option would be to embrace the theoretically equivalent `C-(` -- except iTerm2 only interprets that as a literal 9, and `C-)` as 0. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260754/just-getting-used-to-paredit-in-emacs-on-os-x-how-come-c-doesnt-work) chews on this problem, and gets as far as a tantalizing comment suggesting that `C-(` and `C-)` simply be re-mapped to escape sequences that emacs can map *back* to `C-(` and `C-)` -- but frankly, I haven't a clue how to figure out what escape sequences those should be.

Bringing it all home: has anybody found a way to use all of these tools (Mission Control, iTerm2, Emacs Prelude, smartparens) together without having to re-wire or disable parts of some or most of them? Or: who has the most elegant re-wiring? Anybody figured out the `C-)`-to-escape-sequence-back-to-`C-)` trick yet?

**Edit**

Stabbing in the dark, I've done the following:
1. Set iTerm to send an escape sequence for the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-0 (`C-S-)`) of `SPRTPRN`.
2. Put this in my emacs config:

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map "\eSPRTPRN" [C-right-paren])
(global-set-key [C-right-paren] (kbd "C-)"))
```

...it does not work, but I've a hunch I'm getting closer. I think.

**Edit, Again**

I realized something: the notion that Shift doesn't work here doesn't make sense to me. At least on my emacs install, M-< and M-> jump to the beginning and end of a buffer, respectively -- and to use those commands, I have to actually *press* Meta-Shift-<. Huh.

Comment: How about using `start-process` and write `osascript / apple-script` to control Mission Control instead of system wide shortcuts that conflict with Emacs?  (e.g., "tell application ... mission control .. do the hokey-pokey and turn yourself around . . .")  And, of course, disable any keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences (Keyboard) that are conflicting.

Comment: That could work -- but of course, the nice part about the system wide stuff is... it works system-wide. For those times when I'm not Emacs'ing.

Comment: Would be pretty sweet if I could get Mission Control to do the hokey-pokey, tho.

Comment: You could pick uncommon system-wide shorcuts -- e.g., control+option+command+right-arrow

Comment: That works for getting Mission Control out of the way -- but now I still have to figure out how to get the dang command _in to emacs_. I still get `C-)` sending just `9`.

Comment: How about using `control+c )`, instead of just `control+)`?  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c )") "hello-world")`.  I don't know if you're going to be able to use `C-)` all by itself.

Comment: Why run Emacs inside iTerm?  That seems to be the source of all your trouble!

Comment: @stefan I'm not sure how iTerm is the problem? The native OSX terminal app doesn't do any better. Are you asking why I run it in a terminal at all?

Comment: @lawlist So, this does work -- but it's *really* unweildy. So, technically an answer, but I'd still love to find something better.

Comment: @Gastove: yes, I'm asking why run in a terminal at all?

Comment: @stefan oh man. I am not real excited about getting in to the "emacs in a terminal vs. not" debate, to be honest. I work in terminals, they support my needs, and in all other ways I have a happy workflow. I'd like to leave it at that. Besides -- I'm sure there's a way to get what I'm trying to do done.